# Change Style of Title in HighCharts in ActionResult

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

Here is my code:

```
public ActionResult SeriesWinsChart()
    {
        Highcharts chart = new Highcharts("chart")
            .InitChart(new Chart { PlotShadow = false })
            .SetTitle(new Title { Text = "Series Wins" })
            .SetCredits(new Credits { Enabled = false })
            //.SetTooltip(new Tooltip { Formatter = "function() { return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.y; }" })
            .SetPlotOptions(new PlotOptions
            {
                Pie = new PlotOptionsPie
                {
                    AllowPointSelect = true,
                    Cursor = Cursors.Pointer,
                    DataLabels = new PlotOptionsPieDataLabels
                    {
                        Color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#000000"),
                        ConnectorColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#000000"),
                        Formatter = "function() { return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.y; }"
                    }
                }
            })
            .SetSeries(new Series
            {
                Type = ChartTypes.Pie,
                Name = "Series Wins",
                Data = new Data(new object[]
                {
                    new object[] { "Test1", db.Teams.Where(x => x.TeamName == "Team1").Sum(x => x.SeriesWins)},
                    new object[] { "Test2", db.Teams.Where(x => x.TeamName == "Team2").Sum(x => x.SeriesWins)}
                })

            });

        return View(chart);
    }
```

This is rendering in a partial View.. so my code for that is just:

```
@model DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts


@(Model)
```

I have done research on this topic but it deals with JS which I know is what HighCharts runs off of, but am I able to change the style, font-size of the title within the ActionResult?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your SetTitle() function you can pass css like font, color etc. as follows :

```
.SetTitle(new Title { Text = "Series Wins", Style = "font: 'normal 14px Verdana, sans-serif',color : 'red'" })
```

Let me know if it helps!